# Where does the pejorative meaning of "shower" come from?

Tags: etymology, british-english, offensive-language, pejorative-language

> **shower**  *British informal*
>   a group of people perceived as incompetent or worthless

I think this term is becoming obsolete.  It's certainly not something I've heard in the street recently.  The first place I encountered it was the 1959 film *I'm Alright Jack*.

> *Major Hitchcock:*  They're a shower.  Absolute shower.

According to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shower) it comes from *shower of shit* but there is no justification given.

Comment: I always thought it was a collective noun for "drip"

Comment: It's definitely not obsolete. It's a common enough expression in Britain.

Comment: I've never heard the word used in this sense in the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No less an authority than [Eric Partridge](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tvRp1whVFUsC&pg=PA1064&lpg=PA1064&dq=%22shower%20of%20shit%22%20partridge&source=bl&ots=gR4M9VUz7w&sig=8jou8rI9SAa6U69KPgdWxgX54KQ&hl=en&ei=93O4Tp7oMcLb8AORoe2KBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22shower%20of%20shit%22%20partridge&f=false) seems to think it probably came from *shower of shit*. Which is what I usually say on the few occasions I use the expression in any form, though I'd always assumed *of shit* was a jocular alliteration with some pre-existing meaning of *shower*.

I don't know for sure if Partridge et al are right, but if they are it puts *shower* on a par with [berk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/berk) as being more coarse than many speakers realise.

Until I just looked it up there, I'd never come across what he suggests as the "full" original form - *shower of shit from Shropshire*.

Like *berk*, *shower* might not be the latest cool slang, but I think it's in no danger of becoming obsolete. Especially for those who need/want to insult Shropshire folk!

Answer (score 2):

A little surprisingly, ‘Chambers Slang Dictionary’ gives *shower* only as Australian slang for a dust-storm. It does, however, have a separate entry for *shower of shit* with these three definitions:

> 1. an unimpressive group of people; occas. an individual. 2. A pile of second-rate things. 3. A term of abuse aimed at a single person.

As alternatives, the entry also provides these delightful terms: *shower of cunts,  . . . savages, . . . shites, . . . tom tits, . . . whore’s bastards*  .

Answer (score 0):

The US has the expression 'shit shower', meaning when all went wrong, or we can label a person or persons as a 'shit shower', meaning they can do abs. nothing right.

Comment: You may be confusing *shit shower* with *shit storm* or *shit show*. Googling "shit shower" yields almost no results outside the phrase *shit shower and shave* (which was for a little while a joke/meme).