# Are "flower" and "flour" always homophones?

Tags: nouns, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, homophones

*Flower* and *flour* are [said to be homophones](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/flour#Pronunciation). However, considering the number of different pronunciations (`/flaʊə/` like BrE *sour*, `/flou(-ə)r/` like AmE *sour*, [`/flɑː/` (forvo)](http://www.forvo.com/word/flower/#en) like BrE *car*, etc.) floating around, are they always homophonous for each particular speaker?

**Edit:** As tchrist points out in the comments, the same question could be asked of *dower* and *dour*.

Comment: Anecdotally, I'd say usually but not always. I've heard one person pronounce "flour" as a one-syllable word where they pronounce "flower" as a distinctly two-syllable word. I don't know where they learned to speak that way, and I don't know if it's common where they come from. I'm  pretty sure that English was their first language (but I suppose there's a chance could be wrong).

Comment: Ask also about *dower/dour* which like *flower/flour* are also always homophones — and unlike the many pairs which are not, like *lower/lore, payer/pair, tower/tour, mower/more, layer/lair, power/pour/poor/pore*.

Comment: In crosswords, *flower* is often the cue-word for a *river*, in which context it's pronounced *floe - er*.

Comment: @tchrist Listen to the [girl from Pittsburgh](http://www.forvo.com/word/flower/#en). For some people _hour_, _our_, and _are_ are homophones.

Comment: @coleopterist:  Generally what it means is that, while different people pronounce the words differently from other people (which is part of the variation), almost everybody will pronounce both words the same way -- whichever way that is for them. And they do. Certainly I do, and certainly I know of no American English speaker who's attempted to distinguish between them phonetically.

Comment: _Dour_ is another matter; I happily learned to pronounce it /dʊr/, leaving only _dower_ to rhyme with _scour_. The number of syllables (one, two, one-and-a-half) is another matter for individual variation, especially since many people epenthesize between two resonants like the /w/ of /'flaw-/ and the final /-r/.

Comment: @JohnLawler So, did you consciously force yourself to pronounce _dour_ differently?

Comment: Yes, it's a terrible struggle; so I rarely use it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's water under the bridge.

Comment: @tchrist: Sort of like the French word `fleur`, which is one syllable, but it had an "ou" sound instead of the "eu" sound. I wish I'd recorded it so I could play it back. ;)

Comment: @Edwin: It may be all over and done with from *your* point of view, but those of us who "co-solve" crosswords with blind people get in the habit of saying it both ways for clues like [23D Adherents of “flower power” (4)](http://www.guardian.co.uk/crosswords/prize/25574) *(CAMP = river CAM + P for power)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: And doubtless _contest embattled tower?_ will be _tug-of-war_. It must be very rewarding helping blind people with otherwise near-impossible hobbies.

Answer (score 14):

The words *flour* and *flower* do not only have the same root, but they were also spelled the same until around 1830. (See [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flour).)

Not only did Shakespeare rhyme *hour* with *flower*, but he also sometimes [spelled them the same](http://books.google.com/books?id=Uw4WAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT65&dq=shakespeare+weeds+among+weeds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=j_fsUJfDD-XS2gWZ34DACg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=short%20numbred%20howers&f=false).

> It fears not policy that *Hereticke,*
>   Which works on leases of short numbred howers,
>   But all alone stands hugely pollitick,
>   That it nor growes with heat, nor drownes with showres.

The meter requires that most uses of *flower* I found in his works be pronounced with one syllable.

> To thy faire flower ad the rancke smell of weeds,

but there are a few uses that must be pronounced with two syllables:

> Flower of this purple die,
>   Hit with Cupids archery,
>   Sinke in apple of his eye,
>   When his loue he doth espie.

Thomas Gray, writing one hundred and fifty years later, does the same thing: *hour* and *lower* rhyme:

> While Hope prolongs our happiest hour,
>   Or deepest shades that dimly lower

and *flower* always seems to be one syllable:

> Full many a flower is born to blush unseen,
>    And waste its sweetness on the desert air.

So it appears that they have been homophones, at least in the London dialect, for over four hundred years.

Wordsworth (1770–1850) also appears to have only used the one-syllable pronunciation of *flower*, but Tennyson (1809–1892) used both the one- and two-syllable pronunciations:

> The purple flower droops; the golden bee
>   Is lily-cradled: I alone awake.

Both of these poets rhyme *flower* and *hour*.

My guess is that if somebody currently uses two syllables for *flower* and one syllable for *flour*, the most likely reason is that their pronunciation has been influenced by the spelling.

Comment: *Lower* in this sense is, according to the OED, pronounced to rhyme with *flower* and sometimes spelled 'lour'. *Dour* rhyming with *poor* seems to have a Scottish origin; but who would know more about dourness?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in most english speakers, they are homophones, but depending on  some accents this could change. So you will almost never hear them pronounced differently, however, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, in Singapore and Malaysia English, *flour* is pronounced /flɑː/ (while *flower* is pronounced the same as elsewhere).

---

A [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Singaporeans-pronounce-flour-as-fla) answer (John Tan) claims "that was how the British pronounced it when they were here." (But I doubt any British person ever pronounced it /flɑː/.)

A [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/singapore/comments/16xnjas/pronunciation_of_flour_in_singapore_english/) post argues this pronunciation "is from vowel coalescence typical of traditional RP speakers".

Edit (following comments): I  suspect some British persons did pronounce it something like /flɑ:ə/ and locals then dropped the schwa.

Comment: *"(But I doubt any British person ever pronounced it /flɑː/.)"* - I'm sure they did: it sounds very (almost stereotypical) upper-class."

Comment: Indeed. I remember Terry-Thomas' "You absolute shower" (pronounced "ebsoliute shaə"). It is indeed cut-glass RP.

Comment: @AndrewLeach What would "you absolute shower" mean? " you['re an] absolute show off"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's a pejorative expression, a euphemistic shortening of the full phrase "shower of shit(e)" ("shower" as in "rain shower", not the one derived from the verb "show")

Comment: @herisson I am *very* unfamiliar with the expression "shower of shit(e)" but it makes more sense, thank you!

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I think it's possible some British persons pronounced it something like /flɑ:ə/, but really doubt any ever pronounced it /flɑː/ (as is the standard pronunciation in Singapore and Malaysia today). // By the way, Terry Thomas "You absolute shower": [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oU_HFZ2Tr0)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: [Where does the pejorative meaning of "shower" come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47611/)

Answer (score 0):

I was born in England and raised in Ireland. I pronounce them identically. In some accents, they are pronounced differently. My Malaysian wife pronounces flour as one syllable and flower as two.